# Asymptotics of the general second order affine recursion

Tags: real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, asymptotics, recurrences

What is the general method for finding the aymptotics of large $n$ of the sequence $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ defined by the recursion
$$a_{n} = (\alpha_1n+\alpha_2) a_{n-1} + (\alpha_3n+\alpha_4) a_{n-2}+\delta \tag1$$
where $\alpha_i$'s are constant real numbers and $\delta\in\{0,1\}$ is constant.

Here is [an example](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3386637/64809) of the above recursion and my frustrated attempt at using the generating function for the un-simplified version. That particular example is solvable with a generating function once [it is transformed](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3389236/64809). However, not every recursion of the form $(1)$ can be simplified through a simple transformation.

Comment: Did you try generating functions?

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov: Yes, I did indeed. I added the link to my frustrated attempt at an example.

Comment: is $\delta\in \{0,1\}$ fixed or may depend on $n$?

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Just clarified that in the question.

Comment: $C.n!\alpha_1^nn^{\alpha_2/\alpha_1+\alpha_3/\alpha_1^2}$ I believe if $\alpha_1\alpha_3\ne0$ (similar formulas otherwise).

Comment: What about trying exponential generating functions?

Comment: @HenriCohen: Could you please write out the details of the derivation as an answer?

Comment: @Bullet51: I have tried that and gotten a second-order linear nonhomogeneous ODE which I cannot solve directly (without using the Frobenius method).

Comment: @Hans: I said I believe because I have no rigorous proof, it depends on the initial values. I simply use the Ansatz that the asymptotic is of the form I give (with an extra subexponential term $\exp(-u\sqrt{n})$ which is not needed here), and find the constants. In this way you can also obtain an asymptotic expansion in $1/n$. The only unknown is the constant $C$ which depends on the initial values.

Comment: How did you obtain your ansatz, from numerical computation and plotting the graph?

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Do you have any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know about *the* general method, but here's a recipe for $\delta = 0$.

One can view this as a 3-term recurrence relation, and consider the corresponding orthogonal polynomials. [Favard's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favard%27s_theorem) guarantees such polynomials exist, and in fact [Riesz Representation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem) upgrades the orthogonality to the usual one if you ensure $\alpha_3 n + \alpha_4 < 0$. This transfers the problem to a problem to a problem about asymptotics of orthogonal polynomials, which can be done using multiple methods (WKB, Riemann-Hilbert, amongst many others).

**Example:**

Consider $\alpha_1 = 0, \ \alpha_2 = 2, \ \alpha_3 = -2, $ and $\alpha_4 = 2$. Then, assuming no algebra mistakes, we have (I re-index so I can use Wikipedia)
$$
a_{n + 1} = 2a_n - 2na_{n - 1}, \ a_0 = 1, \ a_2 = 2
$$
This recurrence is satisfied by Hermite polynomials $H_n(x)$ (evaluated at $x = 1$), which satisfy 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^k H_n(x) \ e^{x^2} = 0 \quad \text{ for } k = 0, 1, ..., n-1.
$$
and 
$$
H_{n + 1}(x) = 2xH_n(x) - 2nH_{n - 1}(x)
$$
Now, again the wikipidia page tells me that (this I did not check too carefully, but I know asymptotic expansions of Hermite Polynomials exist)
$$
a_n = H_n(1) \sim e^{1/2} \dfrac{2^n}{\sqrt{\pi}} \Gamma\left( \dfrac{n + 1}{2} \right) \cos \left( \sqrt{2n} - \dfrac{n \pi}{2} \right).
$$

Now, in the general situation, a glance at Chihara's book "[Introduction to Orthogonal Polynomials](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486479293)" (Pages 215 - 217) tells me that for recurrences of the form you give will often be handled using Hermite and Charlier polynomials (maybe others if you get funny about what $x$ value you consider).

P.S. I am new to this, so if this needs downgraded to a comment or is somehow not what you wanted, my bad!

Comment: +1. Very clever connection to the orthogonal polynomials! Short of the treatment for $\delta=1$, it is a full solution.